# Read memory mapped file created by c++ into c#

Tags: c#, c++, memory-mapped-files

Basically I have a binary file which was created using the c++ memory mapped library. I have all the information regarding the struct in c++. I am trying to read that binary file using memory mapped library in c#. Can someone show me any articles/blogs which show how to achieve that?

I am struggling at mapping the c++ struct to c# struct and also the steps required to read and map the content.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First, open the file with a [`FileStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx).

```
var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

Then instantiate a [`BinaryReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.aspx) from that stream. This isn't completely required, but makes working with binary data easier.

```
var reader = new BinaryReader(stream);
```

Next, read in as many bytes as the structure needs, as indicated by [`Marshal.SizeOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.sizeof.aspx):

```
var bytes = reader.ReadBytes(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof (MyStruct)));
```

Then, we "pin" that managed memory so the GC doesn't move it, using [`GCHandle.Alloc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1246yz8f.aspx):

```
var handle = GCHandle.Alloc(bytes, GCHandleType.Pinned);
```

Finally, we convert that buffer to a managed structure, using [`Marshal.PtrToStructure`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ca6d5z7.aspx):

```
var myStruct = (MyStruct)Marshal.PtrToStructure(
                   handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof (MyStruct));
```

Don't forget to free the GCHandle:

```
handle.Free();

    return theStructure;
}
```

[Here is](http://code.cheesydesign.com/?p=572) an example of part of that wrapped up in a generic function.

---

While I haven't tried it, I'm fairly confident this would also work with a using a [`MemoryMappedFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile.createfromfile.aspx) and calling [`CreateViewStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267538.aspx) (which you pass to the `BinaryReader`.)

```
var mmfile = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(path);
var stream = mmfile.CreateViewStream();
var reader = new BinaryReader(stream);
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathon. I will give that a try. do you by any chance know how to do mapping from c++ struct to c# struct? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019499/mapped-c-struct-to-c-sharp-struct