# Mapped c++ struct to c# struct

Tags: c#, c++, struct, memory-mapped-files

I am having trouble mapping the following c++ struct in c# for memory mapping purposes.

```
typedef struct
{
DWORD Data1;
DWORD Data2;
double AverageData[2];
DWORD NumData[2];
} DIRECTIONAL_STATS;

typedef struct
{
DIRECTIONAL_STATS DirectionStats[2];
char  Name[100];
int   StatLength;
} OTHER_STATS;


typedef struct
{
OTHER_STATS SystemStat[64][2];

long LastUpdate;
}STATS;
```

Can someone please shed some lights on how to achieve the mapping? Mapping from c++ type to c# type is fine for me.

However, I don't have any clue how to map nested struct and the explicit array size required.

Update 1:
Managed to map to following c# code:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public struct STATS
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.Struct, SizeConst = 128)]
        public OTHER_STATS[] SystemStat; //64x2
        public long LastUpdate;            
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public struct OTHER_STATS
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.Struct, SizeConst = 2)]
        public DIRECTIONAL_STATS[] DirectionStats;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 100)]
        public char[] Name;
        public int StatLength;
    }       

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
     public struct DIRECTIONAL_STATS
    {
        public UInt16 Data1;
        public UInt16 Data2;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 2)]
        public double[] AverageData;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 2)]
        public UInt16[] NumColdRes;
    }
```

Unsure about the following mapping since it is a multidimensional arrays.

```
public SENTRY_PERFORMANCE_STATS[] Sentry; //64x2
```

Using the above mapping, it is able to run without any exception, however, the data mapped into OTHER_STATS are all wrong.

Can anyone see what I have done wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968960/how-use-pinvoke-for-c-struct-array-pointer-to-c-sharp

Comment: Getting this error.  cannot be marshaled as an unmanaged structure; no meaningful size or offset can be computed. Not sure how to map multi dimensional array. That might be the culprit.

Comment: Thanks jonathon, that only helped me to as far as the update i did on the above mapping. I still unable to read the data out as everything comes out in the form of "?".